# DB migration in Azure pipelines

Tags: node.js, database, azure-devops, sequelize.js, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to automate the DB migration step of app deployment in Azure pipelines?

I have checked `EntityFrameworkCore` but that doesn't seem to fit.

I have a nodejs application with `sequelize` migrations. Is there a way to run the migration with `sequelize-cli` in the pipeline task?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is Shayki's answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT The problem I'm facing is that I cannot connect to db from azure pipeline since db firewall allow only predefined client IPs. Is there a way to add the pipeline VM IP range to firewall?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `sequelize` exists in the [Hosted Agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), but you can install the staff during the pipeline and then run the migration. for example:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

name: sql

steps:
# Install sequelize
- script: "npm install -g sequelize"
  displayName: "install sequelize"

# Install a driver, like mysql2 
- script: "npm install -g mysql2"
  displayName: "install mysql2"

# Install the sequelize CLI
- script: "npm install -g sequelize-cli"
  displayName: "install sequelize-cli"

# Install the migration
- script: "sequelize db:migrate"
  displayName: "run migration"
```